# Problem with utf8 link

Tags: urls

I want to get my taxonomy link like this:
[http://ahanalat.co/محصولات/میلگرد/میلگرد-آجدار/کاوه-تیکمه-داش/](http://ahanalat.co/%D9%85%D8%AD%D8%B5%D9%88%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA/%D9%85%DB%8C%D9%84%DA%AF%D8%B1%D8%AF/%D9%85%DB%8C%D9%84%DA%AF%D8%B1%D8%AF-%D8%A2%D8%AC%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%B1/%DA%A9%D8%A7%D9%88%D9%87-%D8%AA%DB%8C%DA%A9%D9%85%D9%87-%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%B4/)

But when i call it with this function `esc_url( $price_url_link )` it will be return like this:

http://ahanalat.co/%D9%85%D8%AD%D8%B5%D9%88%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AA/%D9%85%DB%8C%D9%84%DA%AF%D8%B1%D8%AF/%D9%85%DB%8C%D9%84%DA%AF%D8%B1%D8%AF-%D8%A2%D8%AC%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%B1/%DA%A9%D8%A7%D9%88%D9%87-%D8%AA%DB%8C%DA%A9%D9%85%D9%87-%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%B4/

Comment: Which context do you want this in? It is normal for characters to be encoded in correct technical/clickable representation of an URL.